# What's the difference between vector of indices vs. one-hot vector when inputting to embedding layer in NLP?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

Lots of NLP tasks require putting inputs into an embedding layer. The output of the embedding layer is then fed to a model such as LSTM.

Say you had a sentence like "I like cats" and "I like dogs".

The vocabulary dictionary would be something like:

```
{'<pad>': 0, 'I': 1, 'like': 2, 'cats': 3, 'dogs': 4}
```

My question is, what would the **input to the embedding layer** look like? Would it be:

1. [1,2,3,0] for "I like cats" and [1,2,4,0] for "I like dogs" ?
2. [1,1,1,0] for "I like cats" and [1,1,0,1] for "I like dogs"?

It seems like it doesn't matter either way, but I have seen #1 used quite often, but I don't know why #2 wouldn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing method depends on the location of the word in the sentence. Hence, two sentences like `I like cat and dog` and `I like dog and cat` which have the same meaning, have two indexing vectors `[1 2 5 3]` and `[1 2 3 5]` for example for the vocabulary `[I, Like, cat, dog]`. There two issues here. First, it is difficult to define a good measure to find the similarity between two sentences. Moreover, the value of indexes does not have any meaning in the numeric space. I mean if the value for a word is `5` and a value of a word is `4`, it does not mean these are more similar than two words with values of `2` and `3`as their difference is `1`.

Therefore, the indexing method due to some misleading the learner and have not a good result in the output.

On the other hand, you can't see these issues on one-hot encoding. Although it is not a perfect representation.

Comment: Hi, these are just inputs to the embedding layer and not direct inputs to the model. The embedding layer would figure out the semantic meaning. But you did hint that the one-hot encoding has no information on the ordering of the words.

Comment: @somethingstrang Hi, please notice that `the indexing method due to some misleading the learner and have not a good result in the output.`. So it has some bad effect on the input to model too.

Comment: I am just wondering since I've seen the #1 case often. For example, in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47205762/embedding-3d-data-in-pytorch, the author converts [ [ [‘w’, ‘h’, ‘o’, 0], [‘i’, ‘s’, 0, 0], [‘t’, ‘h’, ‘i’, ‘s’] ] ] into [ [ [2, 3, 9, 0], [ 11, 4, 0, 0], [21, 10, 8, 9] ] ]. Can you tell me why they did that?

Comment: @somethingstrang it's in the character level and indices have some meaning here! But you are talking about words in sentences.

Comment: Thanks, you said something interesting which I still have one question with. You say that the character level has some meaning with the indices, but why? The character indices simply map from a character to a number defined in a dictionary. Why are words any different? Wouldn't words also be allowed to be mapped to some sort of number defined in a dictionary of words? To me, the underlying structure is identical.

Comment: To follow up with the above comment, the Pytorch tutorial embeddings seem to also use indices in a word dictionary. https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/nlp/word_embeddings_tutorial.html

Comment: @somethingstrang indices in a word dictionary are cool! those indices are used instead of the words in a dictionary. But you are using from the indices of the words in each sentence. So, it will lose the meaning of the words! In pytorch case, a word is always has the same index in all setences  (if there exists). But, in your suggestion it is not! Is that clear?